# Jquery Validation REGEX always fail

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, validation

Jquery validation always fail when correct regex, regex check to see if text in box matches the following format: YYYY-MM-DD. tried all the different ways I could find. Using the jquery-validation gem and the javascript file is loaded correctly as all the other validations work and but it always fails the date.

Javascript file:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function() {
  $("#new_grand_prix").validate({
    rules: {
      "grand_prix[name]": {required: true},
      "grand_prix[laps]": {required: true, min: 0, digits: true},
      "grand_prix[country]": {required:true},
      "grand_prix[date]": {required: true, correctDateForm: true},
    }
  });
  jQuery.validator.addMethod("correctDateForm", function(value, element) {
    var r = new RegExp('^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])');
    var test = r.test($('#grand_prix_date').html());
    return test;
  }, "Date must be in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD");
});
```

View:

```
<script src="validate_new_grand_prix_form.js"></script>
<%= form_with(model: grand_prix, local: true, id: 'new_grand_prix') do |form| %>
  <% if grand_prix.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(grand_prix.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this grand_prix from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% grand_prix.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_area :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :laps %>
    <%= form.number_field :laps %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :country %>
    <%= form.text_area :country %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :date %>
    <%= form.text_area :date %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are at least 2 problems with this code:

**1. The RegExp**

Backslash escapes the next character in a string. For example, `'\hello'` outputs `'hello'`, and `'\\hello'` outputs `'\hello'`. This becomes problematic in your pattern since it's passed as a string.

So, change

```js
var r = new RegExp('^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])');
```

to

```js
var r = new RegExp(/^\d{4}\-(0[1-9]|1[012])\-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/);
```

**2. How to get the input value**

If `$('#grand_prix_date')` is the input, use [val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to get its content.

So, change

```js
var test = r.test($('#grand_prix_date').html());
```

to

```js
var test = r.test($('#grand_prix_date').val());
```

Note that your RegExp will treat `0000-02-31` as a valid date, but I consider that discussion to be out of scope for this question :) Good luck!

Comment: This still triggers the validation and doesnt accept any date